# How to find total number of friends groups

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a friendship graph as follows[image: Friendship graph]

I want to find all the possible group of friends. What is the best algorithm to find these grouping. For example in this graph , possible friendship groups are as follows: 1,2,3,4,12,13,23,123,14,143,124,1234

If I use brute-force algorithm (starting from each vertex and do this 4 times), it generates lots of duplicates.

Comment: could you provide a format for your graph data ?

Comment: note that the most interesting question would be, how to find a linear algorithm which introduces the fewest number of errors ( and defining an error count function )

Comment: @igael I would prefer to store it as adjacency list because graph could be sparse in most cases.

Comment: no problem, provide a format ( while the question remains : *"find the number"* and not *"enumerate them"* )

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) it's NP-complete so you can only use brute-force for detecting such sets. The problem is called `Clique problem` and is one of first identified NP-complete problems.

Comment: Yes it is NPH. I am looking for faster algorithm for sparse graph.

Comment: Thanks I will check it

Comment: According to the OP, `1234` is also a friendship group, but that is not a complete subgraph. OP's problem seems to me to find all possible connected components

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER is 1234 ok?

Comment: yes 1234 is a part of solution. In given graph the answer is 1,2,3,4,12,13,23,123,14,143,124,1234.

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER how is 4 friend with 3?

Comment: @bk2dcradle the problem is , if we count all possible connected components then for 1-2-3-1 we will get 123 as well as for 1-2-3 we will again get 123. hence, duplicate occurs.

Comment: @xenteros 4 is not direct friend of 3 but if common friend 1 joins then 143 form a group.

Comment: @xenteros if we pick 1, adjacent of 1 are 2,3 and 4 now 34 is a subset of 234.  I posted the same thing in your previous answer but you deleted it. Could you please elaborate again your procedure. I am sorry if I could not get your answer. Thanks